# javascript form validation- no popup

Tags: javascript, html, validation

for a uni assignment I need to validate my form before posting it. When an error occurs, there needs to be a text message in the same block as the error-input field (so no pop-up message). I'm not very good at JavaScript so I could really use some help.

Here's my html

```
<div id="form">
    <form name="myForm" method="post"  >
    <p class="head">Deelnemer</p>
        <fieldset id="deelnemer">
            <label class="title">Naam:</label>
                <input type="text" id="txtName" name="txtName" size="15"/>                
        </fieldset>
    <p class="head">Opmerkingen</p>
        <fieldset id="opmerkingen">
            <textarea name="opmerkingen" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
        </fieldset>
    <p id="button"> 
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Aanmelden" onclick="validate()"/>
    </p>
</form>
```

And my Javascript so far (this show a popup message)

```
function validate()
        {
 var userName = document.getElementById("txtName").value;
 if (userName.length == 0)
  {
    alert("Please, enter your name");
    return false;
  }
 else
  {
    alert("Thank you, " + userName);
  }
}
```

I hope someone has an answer for me! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, what you want is just to make appear a message close to the textfield with the error?

For that, you jusst need to modify a little bit your htm and js:

```
<p class="head">Deelnemer</p>

    <fieldset id="deelnemer">

        <label class="title">Naam:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtName" name="txtName" size="15"/>
            <div id="txtNameError" style="display: none;">Please, enter your name</div>
<p class="head">Opmerkingen</p>
    <fieldset id="opmerkingen">
        <textarea name="opmerkingen" rows="5" cols="40">

        </textarea>
    </fieldset>

<p id="button"> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Aanmelden" onclick="validate()"/>
    </p>
</form>
```

And, in your js file, you replace your alert by the id you need to dispay:

```
 {

    var userName = document.getElementById("txtName").value;


    if (userName.length == 0)

    {

    /*alert("Please, enter your name");*/
    document.getElementById("txtNameError").style.display = "block";

    return false;

    }

    else

    {

    alert("Thank you, " + userName);

    }

    }
```

Comment: I can't get it to work. I have my entire form inside a div. If I use the code you have, it won't show to message when I click submit. I think because of display-none, but when I use something different than display: none it'll mess up the entire form and show the div when I load the page.

Comment: It's because your button submit your form whatever happen in your js. You need to change it with: <input type="button" name="submit" value="Aanmelden" onclick="validate()"/> and in your js in your else condition you have to add document.getElementById("myForm").submit();